# IE Scoll set Fix css px

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll, position, absolute

I try a DIV that scrolls in the other element is always at the top edge. Not **fixed** to the window but the parent absolute div

I have the problem that the Internet Explorer jerky when scrolling. Firefox works, but IE jerky.

Does anyone have any idea how I can program it differently?

```
$window.scroll(function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
        });
    } else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: $(this).scrollTop() + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eER6t

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/eER6t/2/

```
<div id="f">
    I'm going to follow you only so far...
</div>
<div>
your content .... .

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use position fixed :

```
$window.scroll(function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
        });
    } else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jHWv3/

Comment: No, i want not a fix element. only absolute to parent element.